# Evaluate $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(iwx)}{x^2-2x\cos(\theta) +1} dx $

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Using contour integration I need to evaluate the following integral. I presume there is a clever way of rewriting the function in terms of z.

Let $\theta \in (0,\pi) $ and $ w > 0$

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(iwx)}{x^2-2x\cos(\theta) +1} dx
$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is, $x = z$ :). Consider whether you need to add an upper semicircle or a lower semicircle, then find the poles.